# Angular: radio input only works with numerical values

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add two simple radio buttons for a user to select their gender. When I set both `[value]`s to a numerical value it works perfectly fine. If I change one of them to a non-numerical value I can still select both options, but the non-numerical option results in the logged value being `undefined`. If I set both options to a non-numerical value, I can only select the last option, again resulting in the value being `undefined`.

`component.html`:

```
<div class="some-class">
  <div class="some-other-class">
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" [value]="m" [(ngModel)]="Gender"
    />
    <label for="male">Male</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="some-class">
  <div class="some-other-class">
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" [value]="f" [(ngModel)]="Gender"
    />
    <label for="female">Female</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

`component.ts`:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    Gender: string = null;

    someFunction() {
        console.log(this.Gender);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious but I can't find it, so any help would be appreciated.

PS. I could still just use 1 and 2 as a value, but the API I need to send the values to only allows 'm' and 'f' for gender. I know it's only one line to change those to 1 or 2, but it seems like an unnecessary extra line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[value]` expects an expression like a property of your component. If you pass just `m` it tries to access the property `m` on your component (which is obviously undefined, you only have `Gender` defined).

Try `value="m"` or even `[value]="'m'"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `[value]="m"` with either `value="m"` or `value="'m'"` as the ones you are using are static and you should use property binding syntax only when you are trying to assign value through variable.

In your case, the `[value]` property binding tries to look for properties m and f respectively and cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

I've used arrays in typescript with ngFor in the template to rather great success:

component.html:

```
<div class="some-class">
  <div class="some-other-class" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" [value]="gender" [(ngModel)]="Gender"/>
        {{ gender }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class SomeComponent{
  genders: string[] = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other']
  Gender: string = null

  someFunction(){
    console.log(this.Gender)
  }
}
```